# Run celery with django on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using environment variables

Tags: django, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run celery on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with my Django app. I followed this great answer of @yellowcap ([How do you run a worker with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761468/how-do-you-run-a-worker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk)). So my `supervisord.conf` looks like this :

```
files:
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh":
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  # Get django environment variables
  celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
  celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

  # Create celery configuraiton script
  celeryconf="[program:celeryd]
  ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
  command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A myappname --loglevel=INFO

  directory=/opt/python/current/app
  user=nobody
  numprocs=1
  stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
  stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
  autostart=true
  autorestart=true
  startsecs=10

  ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
  ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
  stopwaitsecs = 600

  ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
  ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
  ; taking care of its children as well.
  killasgroup=true

  ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
  ; so it starts first
  priority=998

  environment=$celeryenv"

  # Create the celery supervisord conf script
  echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf

  # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
  if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      then
      echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      echo "files: celery.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  fi

  # Reread the supervisord config
  supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

  # Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
  supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

  # Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
  supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd
```

His code worked fine until I decide to migrate some variables which were in my settings.py to my Elastic Beanstalk environment properties.

Indeed, I have the following error when the script is called :

```
for \'environment\' is badly formatted'>: file: /usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py line: 800
celeryd: ERROR (no such process)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your environment line has a trailing quote.  Is that supposed to be there?  `environment=$celeryenv"`

Comment: Yes it's the end of the celeryconf declaration

Comment: Can you please paste the generated celery.conf?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to how Supervisor parses config files [1].

Your environment setting contains an unescaped % character, probably from Django SECRET_KEY.

The following worked for me - try appending `| sed 's/%/%%/g'` to pipe chain here:

`` celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'` ``

Resulting line:

`` celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g' | sed 's/%/%%/g'` ``

[1] https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/291