# Start SQS celery worker on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to start a celery worker on EB but get an error which doesn't explain much.

Command in config file in `.ebextensions dir`:

```
03_celery_worker:
  command: "celery worker --app=config --loglevel=info -E --workdir=/opt/python/current/app/my_project/"
```

The listed command works fine on my local machine (just change workdir parameter).

Errors from the EB:

> Activity execution failed, because: /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:796: RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
>     absolutely not recommended!

and

> Starting new HTTPS connection (1): eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com
>      (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)

I have updated celery worker command with parameter `--uid=2` and privileges error disappeared but command execution is still failed due to

> ExternalInvocationError

Any suggestions what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ExternalInvocationError

As I understand it means that listed command cannot be run from EB container commands. It is needed to create a script on the server and run celery from the script. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131649/2983211) describes how to do it.

**Update:**
It is needed to create a config file in `.ebextensions` directory. I called it `celery.config`. Link to the post above provides a script which works almost fine. It is needed to make some minor additions to work 100% correct. I had issues with schedule periodic tasks (**celery beat**). Below are steps on how to fix is:

1. Install (add to requirements) **django-celery beat** `pip install django-celery-beat`, add it to installed apps and use `--scheduler` parameter when starting celery beat. Instructions are [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes).
2. In the script you specify user which run the script. For **celery worker** it is `celery` user which was added earlier in the script (if doesn't exist). When I tried to start celery beat I got error **PermissionDenied**. It means that **celery** user doesn't have all necessary rights. using ssh I logged in to EB, looked a list of all users (`cat /etc/passwd`) and decided to use **daemon** user.

Listed steps resolved celery beat errors. Updated config file with the script is below (celery.config):

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      # Create required directories
      sudo mkdir -p /var/log/celery/
      sudo mkdir -p /var/run/celery/

      # Create group called 'celery'
      sudo groupadd -f celery
      # add the user 'celery' if it doesn't exist and add it to the group with same name
      id -u celery &>/dev/null || sudo useradd -g celery celery
      # add permissions to the celery user for r+w to the folders just created
      sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/log/celery/
      sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery/

      # Get django environment variables
      celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/%/%%/g' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
      celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

      # Create CELERY configuration script
      celeryconf="[program:celeryd]
      directory=/opt/python/current/app
      ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
      command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A config.celery:app --loglevel=INFO --logfile=\"/var/log/celery/%%n%%I.log\" --pidfile=\"/var/run/celery/%%n.pid\"

      user=celery
      numprocs=1
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      startsecs=10

      ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
      ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
      stopwaitsecs = 60

      ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
      ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
      ; taking care of its children as well.
      killasgroup=true

      ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
      ; so it starts first
      priority=998

      environment=$celeryenv"


      # Create CELERY BEAT configuraiton script
      celerybeatconf="[program:celerybeat]
      ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
      command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A config.celery:app --loglevel=INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --logfile=\"/var/log/celery/celery-beat.log\" --pidfile=\"/var/run/celery/celery-beat.pid\"

      directory=/opt/python/current/app
      user=daemon
      numprocs=1
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/celerybeat.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/celerybeat.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      startsecs=10

      ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
      ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
      stopwaitsecs = 60

      ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
      ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
      ; taking care of its children as well.
      killasgroup=true

      ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
      ; so it starts first
      priority=999

      environment=$celeryenv"

      # Create the celery supervisord conf script
      echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf
      echo "$celerybeatconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celerybeat.conf

      # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
      if ! grep -Fxq "celery.conf" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
        then
          echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
          echo "files: uwsgi.conf celery.conf celerybeat.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      fi

      # Enable supervisor to listen for HTTP/XML-RPC requests.
      # supervisorctl will use XML-RPC to communicate with supervisord over port 9001.
      # Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/911994/supervisorctl-3-3-1-http-localhost9001-refused-connection
      if ! grep -Fxq "[inet_http_server]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
        then
          echo "[inet_http_server]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
          echo "port = 127.0.0.1:9001" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      fi

      # Reread the supervisord config
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

      # Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

      # Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celerybeat

    commands:
      01_killotherbeats:
        command: "ps auxww | grep 'celery beat' | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -9 || true"
        ignoreErrors: true
      02_restartbeat:
        command: "supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celerybeat"
        leader_only: true
```

One thing to focus attention on: in my project `celery.py` file is in the `config` directory, that is why I write `-A config.celery:app` when start **celery worker** and **celery beat**