# How to install libcurl with nss backend in aws ec2? (Python 3.6 64bit Amazon Linux)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, libcurl, pycurl

I have an ec2 instance in AWS running Python3.6 (Amazon Linux/2.8.3) where **I need to install pycurl with NSS ssl backend**.

First I tried it by adding `pycurl==7.43.0 --global-option="--with-nss"` to my `requirement.txt` file but I was getting errors installation errors. So I ended up doing it by adding a `.config` file in `.ebextensions` (that runs during deployment):

```
container_commands:
  09_pycurl_reinstall:
    # the upgrade option is because it will run after PIP installs the requirements.txt file.
    # and it needs to be done with the virtual-env activated
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss pip3 install pycurl --global-option="--with-nss" --upgrade --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed'
```

Pycurl seems to be correctly installed, but the celery worker is not running. The celery worker logs show:

```
__main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I ssh connect to the instance and run `python 3.6 -c 'import pycurl'` I get a more detailed error:

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (nss)
```

So I guess that my problem is that I had previously installed libcurl with openSSL instead of NSS, and hence the mismatch between libcurl and pycurl.

According to another stackoverflow question, for libcurl to be installed with NSS backend I should have installed it with:

```
sudo apt libcurl4-nss-dev
```

But since the server is running Amazon Linux I can't use the `apt` command. So I did instead:

```
yum install libcurl-devel
```

And I guess this is the problem: this installs libcurl with OpenSSL support when I need it with NSS support.

**How can I install libcurl with NSS in Amazon Linux??** (I need NSS because I'm running a Django app with celery using SQS as the broker, and SQS requires NSS).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have pretty much the same stack as you (saw it from other questions): Django / SQS / Celery / Beanstalk. I got it running and had also the issues with pycurl, but I used openssl. I don't think that SQS needs nss, at least for me openssl works fine with Python 3.6 on Amazon Linux 2.8.6.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using openssl and it worked fine. I don't know why I thought SQS needed nss. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue and did manage to fix it :)

1. Retrieve Amazon Linux configure options for `libcurl`:

```
curl-config --configure
```

All options referring to paths can be ignored, but other must be kept if you want the same features than system `libcurl`. Of course, `--with-ssl` will be replaced with `--without-ssl --with-nss`.

1.1 Install prerequisites:

```
sudo yum install libssh2-devel nss-devel
```

(of course you should rather add then to the `packages` > `yum` section of your ebextensions)

2. Compile `libcurl` from source (i chose 7.61.1 to match the one used by Amazon Linux 2018.03):

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.61.1.tar.gz
tar xf curl-7.61.1.tar.gz
cd curl-7.61.1
./configure '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-amazon-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--disable-static' '--enable-symbol-hiding' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-threaded-resolver' '--with-gssapi' '--with-nghttp2' '--without-ssl' '--with-nss' '--with-ca-bundle=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt' '--enable-ldap' '--enable-ldaps' '--enable-manual' '--with-libidn2' '--with-libpsl' '--with-libssh2' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-amazon-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic'
make
sudo make install
```

(of course this should be deployed properly as a Shell script through the `files` section of your ebextensions).

Now you should see `libcurl.so.4` created in `/usr/local/lib`.

3. Define the following envvars for `pycurl` to be compiled using your custom `libcurl`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
PYCURL_CURL_CONFIG=/usr/local/bin/curl-config
PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss
```

4. Run your `pip install`

You can check `pycurl` linked to the right `libcurl`:

```
ldd /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

should show you `libcurl.so.4 => /usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so.4`

And of course `python 3.6 -c 'import pycurl'` should work.

That's it! You should be able to run Celery with SQS.

Answer (score 2):

I had loads of issues getting `pycurl` installed on my Python ec2 instance. First up, `pip` wouldn't install pycurl at all. I had to ssh and run

```
yum install libcurl-devel
```

After this, I added the following line to my `requirements.txt` file so that it included the relevant `ssl` option (`--with-openssl`) as an install option:

```
pycurl==7.43.0.5 --install-option="--with-openssl"
```

Once I deployed a new version with this change in `requirements.txt`, pycurl worked fine, which I tested with:

```
python 'import pycurl'
```

I knew I needed to use `openssl` from the error message

> libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl)