# Unable to get supervisord celery worker process running on elastic beanstalk django app

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I'm trying to get celery beat running on django within an elastic beanstalk environment. I've been following the deployment advice here:

[How to run a celery worker with Django app scalable by AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161691/how-to-run-a-celery-worker-with-django-app-scalable-by-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

After deployment the supervisord process fails to work. This is what's show in the logs:

```
-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/supervisord.log
-------------------------------------
2019-10-28 19:58:35,321 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-10-28 19:58:35,333 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-10-28 19:58:35,333 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-10-28 19:58:35,334 INFO supervisord started with pid 3034
2019-10-28 19:58:36,338 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3118
2019-10-28 19:58:37,805 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-28 19:59:37,279 INFO spawned: 'celeryd-beat' with pid 3543
2019-10-28 19:59:37,289 INFO spawned: 'celeryd-worker' with pid 3544
2019-10-28 19:59:38,023 INFO stopped: celeryd-beat (terminated by SIGTERM)
2019-10-28 19:59:38,325 INFO spawned: 'celeryd-beat' with pid 3552
2019-10-28 19:59:38,383 INFO exited: celeryd-worker (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-10-28 19:59:38,932 INFO exited: celeryd-beat (exit status 1; not expected)
```

I don't understand what these logs are telling me and haven't been able to shed any light on it through my own research.

This is the shell script used to create the process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get django environment variables
celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g' | sed 's/%/%%/g'`
celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

# Create celery configuraiton script
celeryconf="[program:celeryd-worker]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A app_name --loglevel=DEBUG

directory=/opt/python/current/app
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998

environment=$celeryenv

[program:celeryd-beat]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A app_name --loglevel=DEBUG --workdir=/tmp -S django --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid

directory=/opt/python/current/app
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998

environment=$celeryenv"

# Create the celery supervisord conf script
echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf

# Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  then
  echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  echo "files: celery.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
fi

# Reread the supervisord config
supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

# Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

# Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-beat
supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-worker
```

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong? Happy to post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

These are the commands that solved this in the end:

```
sudo yum install -y libcurl-devel python-devel
PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT=''
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && sudo /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 -m pip install pycurl --global-option="--with-openssl"
```